# get char before numeric value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to retrieve the char before a numeric value in javascript or jquery.

Eg

```
$100 should return $

$$100 should return $$

&$ 100 should return &$

$ 25 should return $
```

possible using regex?

Comment: `'$100'.match(/(\D+)\d+/)[1]`?

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You are not supposed to ask plain “is it possible” questions here. You are supposed to go read up on the basics of the techniques involved yourself, and then make an actual attempt. We can help you with that, once you show us what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
var str = "$$$$34534";
var str2 = "$34534";
var str3 = "$@ 34534";
var str4 = "!@#34534";

var patt = /[\D]*/;
 
 console.log(str.match(patt)[0])
 console.log(str2.match(patt)[0])
 console.log(str3.match(patt)[0])
 console.log(str4.match(patt)[0])
```

Regex used is simple: `/[\D]*/` - match any non-digit char